# How to tweak the NodeJS Garbage Collector to schedule fewer Scavenger rounds?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, real-time, latency

I have a real-time application in NodeJS that listen to multiple websockets and reacts to its events by placing HTTPS requests; it runs continuously. I noticed that the response time, at many many times during execution, was much higher than merely the expected network latency, which led me to investigate the problem. It turns out that the Garbage Collector was running multiple times in a row adding significant latency (5s, up to 30s) to the run time.

The problem seems to be related to the frequent scheduling of a Scavenger round to free up resources, due to allocation failure. Although each round takes less than 100ms to execute, executing thousands of times in a row does add up to many seconds. My only guess is that at some point in my application the allocated heap is close to its limit and little memory is actually freed in each GC round which keeps triggering GC in a long loop. The application seems not to be leaking memory because memory allocation never indeed fails. It just seems to be hitting an edge that triggers GC madness.

Could someone with knowledge/experience shed some tips on how to use the GC options that V8 provides in order to overcome such situation? I have tried `--max_old_space_size` and `--nouse-idle-notification` (as suggested by the few articles that tackle this problem) but I do not fully understand the internals of the node GC implementation and the effects of the available options. I would like to have more control over when Scavenger round should run or at least increase the interval between successive rounds so that it becomes more efficient.

Comment: You might want to also optimize things at a different level so you either have more memory available or use fewer small tiny objects that then have to be GCed.  Note: if you know when IS a good time to do GC, you can manually call GC then which might help, but doesn't necessarily keep it from doing GC at other times.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @jfriend00. I tried to call GC manually but it seems that it only calls the Mark-Sweep collector, not the Scavenger. The Scavenger kicks in anyways. I belive some of the following options might provide better control in the new space, do you happen to have experience with any of them?  `--semi_space_growth_factor`, `--experimental_new_space_growth_heuristic`, `--fast_promotion_new_space`

Comment: Just to add my 50 cents . . . I don't know about setting GC options, but if you write the performance-critical code in C++/Rust etc and compile to WASM, which has no GC runtime, you may be able to avoid the problem, if that's a possibility for you.